# Plotting 4 separate lines on a graph

Tags: plotting

I want to plot 4 separate lines on my graph but for some reason Mathematica is linking all my points into a single lines.

My data:

```
v = {3.26797, 4.07436, 5.12821, 5.42005};
m = {0.004, 0.00592, 0.00836, 0.01060};
```

I want a straight line from the origin 
`{0,0}` to the point `{0.004,3.26797}`,
`{0,0}` to the point `{0.00592,4.07436}`,
...,
`{0,0}` to the point `{m[[4]], v[[4]]}`.

I tried the code:

```
ListLinePlot[{{0.004, 10.6797}, {0.00592, 16.6004}, {0.00836, 26.2985},
  {0.01060, 29.3769}}]
```

but all I am getting is a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
v = {3.26797, 4.07436, 5.12821, 5.42005}; 
m = {0.004, 0.00592,0.00836, 0.01060};

 ListLinePlot[Table[{{0, 0}, {m[[i]], v[[i]]}}, {i, 1, 4}],Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Hubble, how would I label each lines? You don't necessarily have to give me the code (although you could and I would study them). Pointing me to a right direction is good (:

Comment: The easiest way is to use PlotLegend.
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/PlotLegends/ref/PlotLegend.html

Comment: I did it =p
Thank you!
And if I would like to label both axes, it's with the function AxesLabel?

Comment: I made an edit.

Answer (score 2):

```
v = {3.26797, 4.07436, 5.12821, 5.42005};
m = {0.004, 0.00592, 0.00836, 0.01060};

ListLinePlot[{{0, 0}, #} & /@ Transpose[{m, v}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd use `MapThread` here, instead of either `Table` or `Map` plus `Transpose`. `Table` has two disadvantages: each element must be accessed by index and the length of the data must be determined. `Map`, on the other hand, cannot do the job by itself and requires `Transpose` or `Thread`. None are great tasks, but represent extra work. `MapThread` is conceptually simpler:

```
MapThread[{{0, 0}, {##}}&, {m, v}]
(*
{{{0, 0}, {0.004, 3.26797}}, {{0, 0}, {0.00592, 4.07436}}, 
 {{0, 0}, {0.00836, 5.12821}}, {{0, 0}, {0.0106, 5.42005}}}
*)
```

That said, `Table` is the simplest if the data sets are of unequal length:

```
Table[{{0,0}, {m[[i]], v[[i]]}}, {i, Min[Length /@ {m,v}]}]
```